# Solving a differential equation by separating variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can one solve the following differential equation by the technique of separation of variables?

$$\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=y^5\ \ \  \text{ when }, \ y(0)=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=y^5$$
$$\frac{1}{y^2}dy=x^2dx$$
$$\int y^{-5}\ dy=\int x^2\ dx$$
$$\frac{y^{-4}}{-4}=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$$
$$-\frac{1}{4y^{4}}=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$$
now, setting $x=0$ & $y=-1$,
$$-\frac{1}{4(-1)^{4}}=\frac{0}{3}+C\implies C=-\frac{1}{4}$$
set the value of $C$ to get the solution

Comment: Thanks a lot Harish! My mistake was setting it up to $$y=(\frac{-4}{3}x^3+C)^\frac{-1}{4}\text{, giving, } -1=(\frac{-4}{3}(0)+C)^\frac{-1}{4}$$ This confuses me, can you explain why this approach gives the wrong answer?

Comment: @SaagarGodithi Possibly taking the 4th roots on both sides may lead to some sign problems, like although $1^4=(-1)^4$, you cannot conclude $1=-1$.

Comment: Please check, your answer is correct same as mine. as you get $C=1$ that gives $$y=\left(\frac{-4x^3}{3}+1\right)^{-1/4}\ \ \text{or}\ \ \frac{-1}{4y^{4}}=\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: The OP was looking for a hint; not the full answer.